# Why is "string" abbreviated into "a" in standard C library function names?

Tags: c

Standard C utility library `stdlib.h` has these function names:

(String as 'a'):

- atof
- atoi
- itoa

(String as 'str'):

- strtoul
- strtol
- strtod

Why is a string sometimes called an "a" and sometimes called an "str"?

Comment: remember, in `C` a `string` is an `"a"`rray of chars

Comment: array to float, array to int, well.. that actually makes sense!

Comment: Just a note: `itoa` is not standard.

Comment: "alphabetic" sounds remotely possible too even though those functions only work with numeric strings :)

Comment: I always had the impression it stood for "ASCII", FWIW.

Comment: "Alpha to integer"... will get you the equivalent integer value of that integer that was represented as "alpha".. since '1' is not the same as 1 and so on...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`a` stands for `ASCII`, so in atoi it is `ASCII` to integer. [See here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1/man/man3/atoi.3). The `ato` family of functions have been deprecated by `str` functions.

Comment: do you know by any chance why stdlib author started using `str` rather than sticking with original convention?

Comment: And even more recently by simple "s", as in `std::stoi` etc in C++11.

Comment: @HowardGuo, since the `a` family lack error handling perhaps it is thought of a mapping from the ASCII set to numbers. But this is just a guess.

Comment: It's important to note that C does not require the use of the ASCII character set. It was originally developed on ASCII-based systems, but there have been C compilers on EBCDIC-based IBM mainframes for decades; on such systems, `atoi` will convert an EBCDIC string to an integer value. The old names have stuck because they can't be changed without breaking existing code.

Comment: How have they been "deprecated" by the `str` functions? The first ANSI C standard codified `atoi` and `strtol` at the same time.

Comment: @Kaz, it says subsumed so I think you are right: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html, also this link says deprecated but I think it is library specific: http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php

Comment: My god the C/C++ standard libraries have some of the worst function names of any language

Comment: In the C11dr specification, I have found no mention of `atoi()` and family being depreciated or subsumed.  Further, `atoll()` exists, presumable new in C11. [atoi() obit?](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/368850.html)